# Error importing pmdarima.arima library in Python

Tags: python, pyramid-arima

Can someone help me resolve the following error message when trying to import the `pmdarima.arima` library for Python?

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-6858fadc5169>", line 1, in <module>
    from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pmdarima/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .arima import auto_arima, ARIMA, AutoARIMA
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pmdarima/arima/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .arima import *
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pmdarima/arima/arima.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .ranking import auc
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import label_binarize
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/testing.py", line 718, in <module>
    import pytest
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _pytest.fixtures import fixture, yield_fixture
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 842, in <module>
    class FixtureFunctionMarker(object):
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 844, in FixtureFunctionMarker
    params = attr.ib(convert=attr.converters.optional(tuple))
TypeError: attrib() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'TypeError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 319, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 353, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1490, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1448, in getframeinfo
    filename = getsourcefile(frame) or getfile(frame)
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 696, in getsourcefile
    if getattr(getmodule(object, filename), '__loader__', None) is not None:
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 733, in getmodule
    if ismodule(module) and hasattr(module, '__file__'):
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_vendored_packages/apipkg.py", line 195, in __getattribute__
    return getattr(getmod(), name)
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_vendored_packages/apipkg.py", line 179, in getmod
    x = importobj(modpath, None)
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_vendored_packages/apipkg.py", line 69, in importobj
    module = __import__(modpath, None, None, ['__doc__'])
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytest.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _pytest.fixtures import fixture, yield_fixture
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 842, in <module>
    class FixtureFunctionMarker(object):
  File "/Users/jdoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 844, in FixtureFunctionMarker
    params = attr.ib(convert=attr.converters.optional(tuple))
TypeError: attrib() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert'
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched up the type error that appears at the end, which led me to a related StackOverflow question whose answer suggested an outdated version of `pytest` would cause issues. I've since upgraded my version of `pytest` which resolved my issue.